# Status QUERY_OVER_LIMIT received as response from google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using your api in my application for several functionalities namely,
-- Get directions to a destination
-- Get distances to several locations
-- Receive location addresses by locating with markers on the map

Application summary (Local-Deals-Now)

The application is a free application to allow local businesses located in Australia, to publish offers/deals related to their business. A user can create a business account (free of charge) and give the location of their business (using google maps api) and add offers/deals to the system by dates and times. Public users/consumers can then view these offers (Or search by distance, location, date, keywords etc:-.... The distance to the offers from the current user location is calculated using distancematrix api).

The application stated above is currently in its development stages and can be accessed via http://www.chuli.fclhosting.com/ . The problem faced was when using the distance matrix APIs to calculate distances to the business from the current logged in user location. I am using the API on the server side as follows

```
$curl = curl_init();
        $uri = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$originString."&destinations=".$destinationsString."&mode=driving&language&sensor=false";
        die($uri);
        $options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $uri,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(),
                CURLOPT_COOKIE => '',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        $responseBody = curl_exec($curl);
        $responseHeaders = curl_getinfo($curl);
        $data = $responseBody;
        $responseContentType = $responseHeaders['content_type'];

        if ((strpos($responseContentType, 'json') !== false) || (substr(html_entity_decode(trim($data)), 0, 1) == "{")) {
            $jsonData = json_decode($data, true);
            if (!is_null($jsonData)) {
                $data =$jsonData;
            }
        }

         for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['origin_addresses']); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($data['destination_addresses']); $j++) {

                $from = $data['origin_addresses'][$i];
                $to = $data['destination_addresses'][$j];
                if($data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['status']=="OK" && $data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['distance']['value']<= ($distance*1000)) {
                    $businessDistanceArray[$businesses[$j]->getId()] = $data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['distance']['text'];
                } else {
                    $businessDistanceArray[$businesses[$j]->getId()] = sfConfig::get('app_offer_not_applicable');
                }

            }
        }
```

Since recently i have started receiving a warning/error stating OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. After googling on the problem (reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) i have grasped that , the above problem occurs either if
--the request limit per day exceeds 25 000 map loads
OR
--by sending too many requests per second

The application as to my knowledge doe not fulfill either one of the above requirements but, still received the warning. Please let me know what i could do regarding this problem in order to overcome this error

Do i have to purchase a business license
OR
Since currently the application is a non profitable one should i apply for a Google Earth Outeach Grant
OR
Just continue without any changes

Here is a sample request sent:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-25.198526444487587,133.20029780312507&destinations=-33.767636351789754,147.41606950000005|-33.905755787445024,151.15402221679688|-32.02195365825273,115.90862329062497|-37.79805567326585,145.01495173583987|-36.8839206402564,144.20859858437507|-31.362071510290537,117.42054612812501|-23.609959,143.72078599999998|-37.819317,145.12404889999993|-37.8186394,145.12360620000004|-37.816506,145.11867699999993|-37.815524,145.12131499999998|-30.708111,134.56642599999998&mode=driving&language&sensor=false

Please look into the info given above. Your feedback would thoroughly appreciated by us

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different limits like Dr.Molle says.  You exceeded the daily limit which allows 2500 elements to be queried in a 24 hour period of time.  When this happens you'll get continuous OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors until that 24 hour time window expires and your quota refreshes.

The other limit to be on the lookout for is the short term limit of 100 elements every 10 seconds.  When you exceed this limit you'll experience the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error for a few seconds (i.e. until the 10 second window is up) and then you'll be able to use the service again.

If this is a user-facing application that loads the Google Maps JavaScript API and performs these distance matrix queries as a result of some user action the JavaScript [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) is definitely worth exploring.  Limits from the JavaScript application are distributed among your website users, not the back-end server.

Comment: I've experinced the 24 hour window so i must be exeeding the daily limit which allows 2500 elements to be queried in a 24 hour period

Answer (score 1):

The [Limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=en#Limits) for the DistanceMatrix-Service is different:

```
100 elements per query.
100 elements per 10 seconds.
2 500 elements per 24 hour period.
```

So please check first, how many origins/destinations you request. When origins*destinations is more than 100, you should have reached the limit for a query and 10 seconds.
In this case(assuming you have only 1 origin), how many "businesses" do you request?

---

**Edit:**
As the request did not exceed the limit for queries/10 seconds, it may be that you repeatedly pass the daily-limit. Your request returns 12 elements, so you will exceed the limit with around 200 requests in 24hours, could this happen?

Comment: I changed my algorithm so that i could overcome the limits

Comment: @Dr.Molle Is this limit based on the deivce id(Android device) or map key used in manifest? Also, the elements mentioned above are elements in the query or elements in response? Bcoz, Google hasn't clearly mentioned anything about the elements we receive in response.. pls do let me know..thanks

Comment: The key doesn't matter, when you request the Webservice via a server the limits will be shared across  the server-IP, when you use it on clientside via the Maps-API for javascript the limits will be per user. The limits doesn't apply to mobile-API's. Related to the elements: the limit applies to the elements in the query, so when you e.g. query 10 origins and 11 destinations with 1 request you hit the limit for a request.

Comment: @Dr.Molle can we increase the limit??when i give 21 points am getting this error..could you please check this once..[my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165133/path-is-not-accurate)

Answer (score 0):

You might be flagged as passing one or other limit if you are sharing hosting with others who are also using the service. Sharing a server may well mean sharing the limits on the service.

Comment: Ohh ..Thanks for the info. But none of the sub domains are using Google map services